# VIM: FileType specific mapping not working when defined in ftplugin

Tags: perl, vim

I am trying to set a mapping for FileType `perl`. The mapping is for the case when I forgot to use semicolon at the end of the line.

So first I tried adding in my .vimrc `autocmd! FileType perl nnoremap <leader>; $a;<esc>` and it worked fine but than I thought of using `ftlugin/perl.vim` .

So I added the below line in my corresponding `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/perl.vim`

```
nnoremap <buffer> <leader>; $a;<esc>
```

but it didn't work.

Any idea why it is  not working ?

My perl version is `perl 5, version 14`.

Comment: It works, here. By the way, `$a` could be shortened to `A`.

Comment: @romainl: Thanks I will do that. But can you think of any reason why it is not working.

Comment: Try `:verbose nmap <leader>;`.

Comment: @romainl: It worked when I added the mapping in `/usr/share/vim/vim73/ftplugin/perl.vim `. Any idea why it is not working when I try to add it in `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/perl.vim`.

Comment: Have you tried it in `~/.vim/ftplugin/perl.vim`?

Comment: @Conner: There is no such folder in my `.vim` directory. Can I copy `/after/ftplugin/` to `~/.vim/ftplugin/` after creating `/.vim/ftplugin`.?

Comment: Yes, you'll have to create it.

Comment: @Conner: It worked thanks. why it was not working previously?

Comment: @Conner: Also post your comment as solution so that I can accept it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try putting the file in `~/.vim/ftplugin/perl.vim` instead of `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/perl.vim`. From `:help after-directory`:

> ```
>                       *after-directory*
> 4. In the "after" directory in the system-wide Vim directory.  This is
>    for the system administrator to overrule or add to the distributed
>    defaults (rarely needed)
> 5. In the "after" directory in your home directory.  This is for
>    personal preferences to overrule or add to the distributed defaults
>    or system-wide settings (rarely needed).
> ```

From `:help ftplugin`:

> If you do want to use the default plugin, but overrule one of the settings,
>   you can write the different setting in a script: >
>
> setlocal textwidth=70
>
> Now write this in the "after" directory, so that it gets sourced after the
>   distributed "vim.vim" ftplugin |after-directory|.  For Unix this would be
>   "~/.vim/after/ftplugin/vim.vim".  Note that the default plugin will have set
>   "b:did_ftplugin", but it is ignored here.

Comment: Strange. The _after_ directory is logically the right place. I can only guess that something has modified and removed the after directory from your `'runtimepath'`.

Answer (score 0):

One thing I just noticed that was driving me crazy: `<buffer>` must be lowercase! Out of habit, I uppercase all of my `<BRACKET>` prefixes... and I had done the same for `<BUFFER>`. None of my ftplugin mappings worked and I couldn't figure it out... until I wasted hours trying different things, only to find that it must be lowercase `<buffer>`.